# Is it right to measure the deeds we do to Allah and say it to another?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, ramadan, islamic-basis

I joined a Ramadan competition recently. They award the winners by measuring the deeds we did to Allah and the person who has the highest points is awarded. Daily they update a form to fill, it basically consists of the number of Thahajjath rakaths prayed, juzu completed, number of dikrs done, amount of sadakah given, number of tharaweeh prayers. Based on the number we get points on daily basis. My point is, is it right to measure what we do to Allah and tell to them?

This question rose because I don't count the number of dikrs I do because I do it with pleasure and go countless, also I don't feel it's right to measure what we do to Allah because Allah SWT doesn't give us countless blessings not by measuring. It's just eternal is what I think.

I want to know whether this competition is right or wrong and if its wrong I am ready to quit at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

In appearance this is a good match. Probably the designers of this contest were thinking of spreading religious teachings and worships, and they wanted to encourage the youth to worship with this contest.
2: 148 says:so take the lead in all good works. The result of the most superficial translation of this verse is this contest that you say.
But let's go a little deeper in appearance. What is the philosophy of worship?
good work, in Quranic culture, it is a blessing that is perfection or leads a person to perfection. Hence, God asks people to compete in charity, which means perfectionism, and to achieve it in a short period of time.
Worship that is calculated in this competition will only receive a worldly reward and, unfortunately, will not have any positive effect on the transcendence of the human soul and thought.
This is the counting and recording of daily worships of hypocrisy in worship, which is opposed to sincerity in intention, and according to the Shari'a, polytheism is forbidden and it also invalidates worship.

Answer (score 0):

According to the view of a lot of scholars, the competition was right.

The organizers of the competition wanted to make you worship more. People did good deeds because of the competition. Most of the people did good deeds for Allah and told what they did to the organizers. For this reasons, a lot of scholars like this kind of competition.

But according to Imam Malik (R),
This kind of competition is not good because it makes people do good deeds to win the competition but not to please Allah.

For doing worshipping to win competitions, one will not get awarded in the afterlife. And worships like this gets invalided.

However, the participants of this kind of competitions nowadays worship Allah to please him and pleasing him is their only intention of worship. Then they stated their good deeds on the competition to win the prize too. So this kind of competitions are good. But be cautious when, when competiting in a competition like this, make sure that the intention of your worship is to please Allah only.